# How to search more than a keyword with UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

HI, 
I successfully perform a search within arrayTags with the following code, where arrayTags is the array of a field of each XML element, named "tag". The problem is that, let's say, tag has three words: red, white, blue. If I perform a search "red" or "white, blue", or whatever exactly included in a tag element, everything is OK. But if I search "red white", the search returns nothing.
Practically, the search returns results only if I search exactly what is included in the arrayTags, but not non-consecutive words.
Do you know how can I solve this problem? Thanks so much!

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{


     [resultArray removeAllObjects];

     NSString *cellTitle;
     for (cellTitle in arrayTags){

      NSString *stringa = cellTitle;
      NSRange range = [stringa rangeOfString:searchText];

      NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:range];
      if (result == NSOrderedSame){

       int posizione = [arrayNames indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:cellTitle];

       [result Array addObject:[arrayNames objectAtIndex:posizione]];


      }
     }

     [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has two or three aspects:

(1) You must define, what is a word *separator* and what *belongs* to the word you are looking for. For example, "A, B" can mean, "look for 'A' and 'B'", or it can mean "look for 'A' and '_B'" (undescore indicates the blank)
Probably, you want to divide searchText like this:

```
NSArray *listItems = [searchText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                      [characterSetWithCharactersInString:@", "]];
```

Perhaps, you want to eliminate whitespaces from the listItems objects and empty objects from listItems afterwards.

(2) Only afterwards, you can decide *how* to look for, what you got from stage (1), for example by creating a predicate which looks for all objects in listItems:

```
NSPredicate *inPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF IN %@",
                           listItems];
NSArray* filteredArray = [arrayTags filteredArrayUsingPredicate:inPredicate];
```

Note that this predicate is case sensitive, so make your own for other requirements!

(3) filteredArray probably should be a member of your view class and is the new tableDataSource. But, there are a few subtleties to solve: empty search texts, switching the data source from filtered to non-filtered content etc.